# How to use boost preprocessor to generate accessors?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

For example

```
class A
{
    int m_x;
    float m_y;
    double m_z;

    int x() const {return m_x;}
    float y() const {return m_y;}
    double z() const {return m_z;}
};
```

becomes like

```
class A
{
    MY_MACRO((int)(float)(double), (x)(y)(z));
};
```

Please use boost prerocessor sequence to do it because this macro will combine with other existing macros which already use boost preprocesor sequence.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have an easier time manipulating `((int, x)(float, y)(double, z))`. Without testing it, some macro taking a type and a base name could generate the declaration and the accessor and the sequence foreach could simply pass the element to that, giving it two arguments per sequence element. It also becomes easier to keep track of which member has which type. I'm unaware of any sorcery to split an argument by a space, but if possible, it could be `((int x)(float y)(double z))`.

Comment: The functions should be public

Comment: Eh, it's actually not as great as I envisioned. The argument has to go through several layers of macros, so it messes up the intermediate ones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disclaimer:You should probably wait in case a better answer appears even if you are satisfied with this answer, because I'm far from an expert and these may not be the best approaches.

**1st approach:**

```
//two different sequences
struct A
{
    MY_MACRO1((int)(float)(double),(x)(y)(z))
};
```

I think this approach gives the less scary-looking macro:

```
#define DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER1(R,TYPES,INDEX,NAME) \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(INDEX,TYPES) BOOST_PP_CAT(m_,NAME);

#define DEFINE_ACCESSOR1(R,TYPES,INDEX,NAME) \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(INDEX,TYPES) NAME(){ return BOOST_PP_CAT(m_,NAME); }

#define MY_MACRO1(TYPES,NAMES) \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER1,TYPES,NAMES) \
public: \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(DEFINE_ACCESSOR1,TYPES,NAMES)
```

`MY_MACRO` gets two sequences: `TYPES` and `NAMES`. In order to declare the data members I use a `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I` on the sequence `NAMES` using the macro `DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER1` and having the sequence `TYPES` as data. This "invokes" `DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER1` with 4 parameters: `R` which is unused (and I have no idea what it does), `TYPES` (the sequence of types), `INDEX` (tells in which iteration we are right now, starting at 0), and `NAME` (the element of the original `NAMES` sequence that corresponds with this iteration).
The "bodies" of `DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER1` and `DEFINE_ACCESSOR1` are simple, we simply get the `INDEX`th element in the types sequence, and concatenate `m_` with `NAME`.

---

**2nd approach:**

```
//just one sequence but you need to put two sets of parentheses around each pair
struct B
{
    MY_MACRO2(((int, x))((float,y))((double,z)))
};
```

This one is still fairly simple, but has the inconvenient of having to use double parentheses.

```
#define DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER2(R,_,TYPE_AND_NAME) \
BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,TYPE_AND_NAME) BOOST_PP_CAT(m_,BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,TYPE_AND_NAME));

#define DEFINE_ACCESSOR2(R,_,TYPE_AND_NAME) \
BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,TYPE_AND_NAME) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,TYPE_AND_NAME)(){ return BOOST_PP_CAT(m_,BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,TYPE_AND_NAME)); }

#define MY_MACRO2(TYPES_AND_NAMES) \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER2,_,TYPES_AND_NAMES) \
public: \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DEFINE_ACCESSOR2,_,TYPES_AND_NAMES)
```

This time there is only one sequence so we won't need the index in the helper macros. For this reason `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` is used on TYPES_AND_NAMES using the macro `DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER2` and without passing any extra data. This macro receives three "arguments": `R` again unused, `_` (or `DATA`, also unused here), and `TYPE_AND_NAME` (a tuple in the form `(TYPE,NAME)`).
In the "bodies" of the two helper macros `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM` is used to get either the type(with index=0) or the name(with index=1). This macro needs to be passed the size of the tuple, the index of the element you want and the tuple.

---

**3rd approach:**

```
//one sequence but the macro is more complex
struct C
{
    MY_MACRO3((int,x)(float,y)(double,z))
};
```

This macro borrows heavily from `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` and similar macros.

```
//Heavily "inspired" from BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
#define CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0(X, Y)  \
    ((X, Y)) CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_1
#define CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_1(X, Y)  \
    ((X, Y)) CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0
#define CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0_END
#define CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_1_END

#define DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER3(R,_,TYPE_AND_NAME) \
BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,TYPE_AND_NAME) BOOST_PP_CAT(m_,BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,TYPE_AND_NAME));

#define DEFINE_ACCESSOR3(R,_,TYPE_AND_NAME) \
BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,TYPE_AND_NAME) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,TYPE_AND_NAME)(){ return BOOST_PP_CAT(m_,BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,TYPE_AND_NAME)); }

#define MY_MACRO3(TYPES_AND_NAMES) \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECLARE_DATA_MEMBER3,_,BOOST_PP_CAT(CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0 TYPES_AND_NAMES,_END)) \
public: \
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DEFINE_ACCESSOR3,_,BOOST_PP_CAT(CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0 TYPES_AND_NAMES,_END))
```

In this approach the helper macros are basically unchanged. The only (big) difference is that the sequence used in the for_each is not simply `TYPES_AND_NAMES` but `BOOST_PP_CAT(CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0 TYPES_AND_NAMES,_END)`. This is a clever trick to force the double parentheses. It works like this:

```
CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0(int,x)(float,y)_END
    //CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0(A,B)->((A,B))CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_1
((int,x))CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_1(float,y)_END
    //CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_1(A,B)->((A,B))CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0
((int,x))((float,y))CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0_END
    //CREATE_MY_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER_FILLER_0_END->
((int,x))((float,y))
```

---

[Running on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ac9bef8c1b6ed87)

Comment: Darn, I tried approach 2 before, even with the extra parentheses, and hit a roadblock :p I think the better answer we're looking for is just to do it without macros, though. It should be very possible to make, say, an editor extension to do this and produce normal code, or even a snippet if you'd rather have a section of `public: blah; private: blah;` things.