# Creating members from variadic macro arguments

Tags: c++, macros, boost-preprocessor

I'm attempting to create vertex structs in OpenGL by using macros to define the vertex basics and having the macro eventually generate the boilerplate code needed for use with OpenGL (`glGetAttribLocation`, `glEnableVertexAttribArray`, `glVertexAttribPointer` etc.).

My macros are defined as such:

```
#define DEFINE_GPU_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE(R, DATA, ELEM) BOOST_PP_CAT(ELEM, DATA);

#define DEFINE_GPU_VERTEX(NAME, ...) struct NAME##_gpu_vertex_t \
{ \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DEFINE_GPU_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE, _, __VA_ARGS__) \
}
```

This is a sample of how I intend to use the macro:

```
DEFINE_GPU_VERTEX(bsp,
((vec3_t), position),
((vec3_t), normal),
((vec2_t), texcoord));
```

Where the first argument (`bsp`) is the name prefix, and all variadic arguments are pairs of types and names of attributes.

I expect it to generate a struct definition like so:

```
struct bsp_gpu_vertex_t
{
    vec3_t position;
    vec3_t normal;
    vec2_t texcoord;
}
```

However, it appears to generate an empty struct.  What am I doing wrong here?

I'm not familiar with C macros, let alone Boost macros as I've never really had reason to use them or learn what makes them tick until now.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Get the preprocessed form (e.g. using `g++ -C -E` or by using appropriately your compiler and IDE) and look inside with an editor or pager (e.g. `less`). Also tell what compiler and operating system you are using, and what is your compilation command.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: `BOOST_PP_**SEQ**_FOR_EACH` requires a [sequence](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/doc/data/sequences.html) and you are not providing one. There is [a macro](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/variadic_to_seq.html) that converts variadic data to a seq that may help. I believe the "usual" way to do this (at least the one used in fusion adaptations/definitions of structs) is to use directly a sequence. The 2nd and 3rd approaches in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309309/how-to-use-boost-preprocessor-to-generate-accessors/24312646#24312646) could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this may not answer your original question. It is not even an answer, but rather a question:

Have you considered generating these `struct`-s using a high-level language instead of C macros?

As you have already found out, C macros are clumsy and difficult to debug. I would rather write a script (say, in Python, but any scripting language with well developed string processing capabilities would do) that would output a `opengl_boilerplate.h` file that contains your `struct` declarations. You would then invoke this script when your software is being built. I don't know how to do that with VS2013, but maybe running it once is enough (depends on your project).

Comment: An interesting idea, but it does a couple things I don't want to happen.  First, it creates a dependency on having Python installed on the machine that's compiling it.  It also adds another build step that could be avoided by using the macros as I initially planned.

Comment: Yes, these are valid points to consider. FWIW, I always use CMake (http://www.cmake.org) to build my C++ projects and it can be used for this sort of header file generation with possibly less hassle. The project depends on CMake anyway and the extra build step is being taken care of by CMake "free of charge". It can generate VS projects. Maybe you can have a look at that option too.