# Variadic macros: Reuse variadic arguments (Boost.Fusion)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I am working on a kind of "data-variable" framework. Here, structs are defined and adapted as Boost.Fusion sequences using the macro `BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_ASSOC_STRUCT`.

**Brief context:**

To define two adapted structs `foo` and `bar`, I use:

```
#define VAR(VARNAME) vardefs::VARNAME
#define VAR_PARENTHESES(VARNAME) (vardefs)(VARNAME)

// ========================================================
#ifndef VARNAME_
#define VARNAME_ foo // <- Variable name
namespace VAR(VARNAME_)::keys{
    struct foo1;
    struct foo2;
    struct foo3;
}
namespace VAR(VARNAME_) { struct index; }

BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_ASSOC_STRUCT(
    VAR_PARENTHESES(VARNAME_), type,
    (char, foo1, VAR(VARNAME_)::keys::foo1)
    (int, foo2, VAR(VARNAME_)::keys::foo2)
    (float, foo3, VAR(VARNAME_)::keys::foo3)
)
#endif
#undef VARNAME_
// --------------------------------------------------------

// ========================================================
#ifndef VARNAME_
#define VARNAME_ bar // <- Variable name
namespace VAR(VARNAME_)::keys{
    struct bar1;
    struct bar2;
}
namespace VAR(VARNAME_) { struct index; }

BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_ASSOC_STRUCT(
    VAR_PARENTHESES(VARNAME_), type,
    (double, bar1, VAR(VARNAME_)::keys::bar1)
    (float, bar2, VAR(VARNAME_)::keys::bar2)
)
#endif
#undef VARNAME_
// --------------------------------------------------------
```

Now one can create instances of `foo` and `bar` by using:

```
VAR(foo)::type fooI;
VAR(bar)::type barI;
```

The associative keys can be used like this:

```
auto a = boost::fusion::at_key<VAR(foo)::keys::foo3>(fooI).
auto b = boost::fusion::at_key<VAR(bar)::keys::bar2>(barI).
```

This approach might be useful down the line.

Lastly, there are tags for the structs themselves:

```
VAR(bar)::index
VAR(foo)::index
```

I can use the later as type-keys in other Boost.Fusion sequences, e.g. `boost::fusion::map`.

**Question:**

Notice that, for each of the two structs, and since I am defining an associative sequence, I have to use the struct-field names (`foo1`, `bar2`, ...) three times each.

What I would like instead, is to define the above two structs as this:

```
// ========================================================
DEFINE_DATAVAR_STRUCT(
    foo,
    (char, foo1)
    (int, foo2)
    (float, foo3)
)
// --------------------------------------------------------

// ========================================================
DEFINE_DATAVAR_STRUCT(
    bar,
    (double, bar1)
    (float, bar2)
)
// --------------------------------------------------------
```

I only need to define the variadic macro `DEFINE_DATAVAR_STRUCT`. This is what I need help for. The problem for me, is to reuse variadic arguments so that they can appear in more than place in the generated code. Somehow, Boost.Fusion is doing this with no problem somehow (by relying on Boost.PP).

**My own research:**

I have looked at the Boost.PP library, but I am not doing very good progress here. Since the Boost.Fusion library is doing this already, there must be a way to achieve the same variadic functionality, similar to the `BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_ASSOC_STRUCT` macro.

The Boost.Fusion macro `BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_ASSOC_STRUCT` is defined on lines 40-50 in [.../define_assoc_struct.hpp](https://github.com/boostorg/fusion/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/define_assoc_struct.hpp#L40). It seems much of the magic to build these macros is to be found in [.../define_struct.hpp](https://github.com/boostorg/fusion/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/detail/define_struct.hpp#L413) (especially the macro `BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT_IMPL` on line 413). This file also takes advantage of a lot of Boost.PP.

**Compiler:** Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (GCC, Clang are not options right now).

**Boost:** 1.64.0.

Comment: I'd simply generate the code or revamp the existing BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT macro (copy it and make it emit the code you crave instead)

Comment: @sehe That's a great idea. Exactly what I had in mind actually. My problem is utilizing the `__VA_ARGS__`, so that I can get same variadic behaviour as the Boost.Fusion macro. Perhaps I can just copy the Boost.Fusion implementation, not sure. I will update the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively easy to construct a macro that generates all your boilerplate from an invocation of your preferred macro:

```
DEFINE_DATAVAR_STRUCT(
    bar,
    (double, bar1)
    (float, bar2)
)
```

In this macro you have two arguments: a name (`bar`) and a "sequence" of tuples (`(double,bar1)(float,bar2)`). I put "sequence" in quotes because in order to have a sequence of tuples that can work with Boost.Preprocessor macros you need to have each tuple delimited by 2 sets of parentheses. In the example below most of the complexity is caused by the solution to this problem (there is more information about this in approach 3 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24312646/2417774).

---

[Running on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e6zTMhmyH95GyIzC)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/define_assoc_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at_key.hpp>



#define VAR(VARNAME) vardefs::VARNAME
#define VAR_PARENTHESES(VARNAME) (vardefs)(VARNAME)

//THIS IS ONLY NEEDED IN ORDER TO GET 2 SETS OF PARENTHESES
//Heavily "inspired" from BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
#define GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE_FILLER_0(X, Y)  \
    ((X, Y)) GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE_FILLER_1
#define GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE_FILLER_1(X, Y)  \
    ((X, Y)) GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE_FILLER_0
#define GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE_FILLER_0_END
#define GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE_FILLER_1_END

#define GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE(MEMBERS) BOOST_PP_CAT(GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE_FILLER_0 MEMBERS,_END)

//THESE AREN'T ACTUALLY REQUIRED BUT HELP WITH READABILITY
#define DATAVAR_GET_TYPE(TUPLE) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,TUPLE)
#define DATAVAR_GET_NAME(TUPLE) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,TUPLE)

//THESE ARE THE HELPERS THAT ACTUALLY GENERATE THE VARIABLE PARTS OF THE MACRO
#define GENERATE_STRUCT_KEYS(_,__,TUPLE) struct DATAVAR_GET_NAME(TUPLE);
#define GENERATE_STRUCT_DEFINITION_SEQ(_,NAME,TUPLE) (DATAVAR_GET_TYPE(TUPLE),DATAVAR_GET_NAME(TUPLE),VAR(NAME)::keys::DATAVAR_GET_NAME(TUPLE))

// ===============================================================================================
#define DEFINE_DATAVAR_STRUCT(NAME,MEMBERS)                                                      \
namespace VAR(NAME)::keys{                                                                       \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(GENERATE_STRUCT_KEYS,_,GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE(MEMBERS))             \
}                                                                                                \
namespace VAR(NAME) { struct index; }                                                            \
BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_ASSOC_STRUCT(                                                                \
    VAR_PARENTHESES(NAME), type,                                                                 \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(GENERATE_STRUCT_DEFINITION_SEQ,NAME,GENERATE_DATAVAR_SEQUENCE(MEMBERS))\
)
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// ========================================================
DEFINE_DATAVAR_STRUCT(
    foo,
    (char, foo1)
    (int, foo2)
    (float, foo3)
)
// --------------------------------------------------------

// ========================================================
DEFINE_DATAVAR_STRUCT(
    bar,
    (double, bar1)
    (float, bar2)
)
// --------------------------------------------------------


int main()
{
    VAR(foo)::type fooI{'a',1,2.0f};
    VAR(bar)::type barI{1.0,2.0f};

    std::cout << boost::fusion::at_key<VAR(foo)::keys::foo1>(fooI) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::fusion::at_key<VAR(foo)::keys::foo2>(fooI) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::fusion::at_key<VAR(foo)::keys::foo3>(fooI) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::fusion::at_key<VAR(bar)::keys::bar1>(barI) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::fusion::at_key<VAR(bar)::keys::bar2>(barI) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks! I knew it probably could be done with relative ease since Boost.Fusion is doing it. I was planning to dive into the preprocessor-macros myself. I had optioned for a solution without keys for structure-fields, but now I can add the full solution. Great!

Comment: If there is anything you don't understand, don't hesitate to ask. Whenever I have more time I'll try to explain better (at all really) what I have done.